# Passing flags for functions via accessors - which JavaScript pattern is it?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, node.js, socket.io

I noticed the following pattern in [socket.io-node](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io):

```
// e.g. 1
socket.volatile.emit('bieber tweet', tweet);

// e.g. 2
socket.broadcast.json.send({ a: 'message' });
```

more generally, it seems to be of the style:

```
someObject.functionFlagA.functionFlagB.functionFlagEtc.someFunction(/* etc */);
```

What is this pattern called, where you add flags which may affect the execution of a function, in a chain of accessors which each return the target function (with any other available/appropriate chainable accessors)? When is it appropriate over, say, just passing some parameters to a function?

Looking at it gave me the idea of creating a `sync` object for my HTML5 web app like so:

```
// Saves someObj to localStorage AND to server-maintained session
sync.toLocalStorage.toServer.save(someObj);
```

...since it would be more self-documenting than:

```
// Saves someObj to localStorage AND to server-maintained session
sync.save(someObj, true, false, true);
```

Is this an appropriate use of above pattern?

---

**EDIT 2011-12-06 13:06:15**

For the curious, this is how socket.io implements it:

```
Socket.prototype.__defineGetter__('volatile', function () {
  this.flags.volatile = true;
  return this;
});
```

Which is used in chain to ultimately call the following internal function which sends a packet and clears the flags:

```
Socket.prototype.packet = function (packet) {
  /* snip */
  this.setFlags(); // clears this.flags

  return this;
};
```

Comment: I don't think the example that you gave is equivalent to the usage in the socket.io example. The socket.io example actually navigates through different levels (objects) while your example is staying in the same level and adding objects to some kind of internal stack. At least from the usage, that's how it appears.

Comment: The [three of them](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L93) in the socket.io source seem to add the flags internally, then execute the end function (which subsequently clears the flags).

Comment: ...can't vouch for what other parts of the API do, though. I guess it could be implemented by some chain of objects with a shared prototype. But the socket.io link is more or less how I imagined it being done, with the 'stack' being maintained in `this.flags` and 'unwound' at the end of the target function block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call it an example of a **fluent interface**.

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface):

> In software engineering, a fluent interface (as first coined by Eric
>   Evans and Martin Fowler) is an implementation of an object oriented
>   API that aims to provide for more readable code. A fluent interface is
>   normally implemented by using method chaining to relay the instruction
>   context of a subsequent call.

Of course in your example you have properties instead of methods. But looking at the socket.io-node code, the 'properties' are programmed as `__defineGetter__` so you might as well say they are methods.

With regards to your sync object for HTML5: think about the state of the sync object after calling save. Is it reset to its original state or does it remember the configuration? What happens if you call save twice in a row?

If it's just about readability, you can also have callers pass in the configuration like so:

```
sync.save(someObj, { toLocalStorage: true, toServer: true });
```

Comment: That sounds convincing - if getters and setters are just syntactic sugar around a method, then it applies exactly. As for your alternative suggestion, it also sounds like it would solve the same problem. Presumably if you have `obj.verb( /* ... */ )` then the arguments being *verb'd* go at the start (since they're documented by the method name), and all other parameters go in an object literal at the end?